# parsing data from files with numbers in name to a single file according to numbering

Tags: linux, parsing, sed, naming

I have a list of files containing forces as the only number as follows.

```
Force1.txt
Force2.txt
Force3.txt
Force4.txt 
Force5.txt
. . .
. . . 
. . .
Force100.txt
```

I want to put all these forces in the file with the same order. However , when I use the following command to 
arrange them in the single file.

```
sed -n '/^[0-9.]*$/w Result.txt' Force*.k
```

I mean the input from above files is listed in output file in the following order-

```
Force1.txt
Force10.txt
Force2.txt
Force3.txt
Force4.txt 
Force5.txt
. . .
. . . 
. . .
Force99.txt
```

The problem is that the linux collects the data with this command in an order and not according to the 
precedence in number. Any suggestion for this?

best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest one, though not most efficient:

```
for i in `seq 100`; do ls Force$i.txt; done
```

Comment: it also doesnt work. It just listed the names of the files in an order and not the data inside those files. and still the same thing.  the files names were also not in a numerical order.

Comment: @hamadkhan: If you want to concat the files, you'll obviously need to replace `ls` by `cat`. The file names are by design ordered  `Force1.txt`, `Force2.txt`, ..., `Force100.txt` in the output of this shell command.

Comment: i used you concept and used already the cat and then echo >> for embedding the data at the end of the file.. thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Split on the "e" and sort by number in "column" two:

```
ls Force*.txt | sort -n -k 2 -t 'e' |xargs cat
```

Comment: its giving the same result as I have mentioned in the problem. so it doest work unfortunately.

Comment: in that case I only get the names of the files, I used               ls minimumThickness*.k | sort -n -k 2 -t 'e'    > results.k                    and it results in a list of files and that also in the wrong order. I want the data to be extracted  from the these in the numerical order.

Comment: You have to use the letter before the * in the -t argument for sort. ie: `ls minimumThickness*.k | sort -n -k 2 -t 'e' > results.k`. But this only works if you don't have a double character before the number... Can you change the names of the files?

Comment: Maybe `rename minimumThickness minimumThickness- *.k` and then use the "-" character for the -t sort argument.